# Configure IntelliJ Ultimate to understand ES6 Syntax

Tags: intellij-idea, ecmascript-6

I'm using Intellij Idea Ultimate 2019.1 for an AngularJS Project. Whenever I use ES6 syntax within my project, like declaring a `const` variable, IntelliJ puts a red underline under `const` with the message:

```
JSHint: 'const' is available in ES6 (use 'esversion: 6') or Mozilla JS extensions (use moz). (W104)
```

How do I follow the suggestion so the IDE understands ES6 syntax and no longer shows me those warnings?

Comment: Did you set your JavaScript language version to ECMAScript 6 under "Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript"?

Comment: yeah @buboh I just checked and I have that setting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable it in **Settings | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Code Quality Tools | JSHint** or you can attach `.jshintrc` to your project and add this

```
{
    "esversion": 6
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: It would help more if we knew where this .jshintrc file is located. PHPStorm could be a little more friendly in helping answer that question!

Answer (score 0):

**Updated setting:**

Settings | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Code Quality Tools | JSHint | Enforcing Options:
Warn about incompatibilities with the specified ECMAScriptversion: ***[add 6 here]***